# unable to install angular with nodejs version 8

Tags: angular

I have installed node v8.17.0 and npm 6.13.4, when I try to install angular with npm install -g angular cli on centos 7 I am getting an error message.
is there any version of angular that works well with nodejs version 8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToV23.png)

Comment: If I were you, I'd simply try different versions of Angular, starting with `npm install -g angular-cli@8` and then going with 7 and finally 6

Comment: @ShamPoosham i tried the same but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new versions of Angular (v9):

> Angular requires a current, active LTS, or maintenance LTS version of Node.js.

Source: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Current, active LTS or maintenance LTS versions can be found on Node.js documentation but basically v10, 12 + 13 (soon to be 14) are supported: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/. V8 of Node came off of its maintenance cycle on Dec 31 2019. It is unadvisable to continue using this version of node.

Angular 6 would work with node 8 although would not recommending updating from an unsupported version of angular and node to another unsupported version of angular and node, if it can be helped.

Comment: Actually my application currently uses nodejs 6 angular 2 so before moving to the higher version I want to test it with nodejs version 8 but I am not able to install angular on that..

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the question. Angular 6 would work with node 8 by the looks of the old angular documentation. I would wonder why you would go to the effort of upgrading your application to an already unsupported version of both node and angular?

Comment: I am new to angular, this application currently uses Node6 version and angular version 1.0.0beta24(which is angular 2) is it still better to continue with this versions, as Nodejs 6 and 8 are both unsupported versions or to upgrade it to new versions

Comment: This depends on your circumstances and your project requirements. Developing on older platforms is often fine for personal projects, proof of concept etc. If the platform allows you to do what you need it to do then fine. However, if it is going into production and especially if a client has commissioned the work, I would advise delivering an application built on the latest, or certainly more up-to-date, platform. I would advise updating both node and angular to the latest and making the changes necessary in most circumstances.